# can't focus a textbox using $('input[name="rate"]').focus(); method

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Friends I have following code in a javascript function that is assigned to `onblur` event on `<input type="text" name="rate" />`. `#NewOrder` is a div and `input[name=quantity]` is also a `input type="text"`. These both input elements are inside `#NewOrder` div.

```
function addMaterial() {
    var qnty, rate;
    if (Number($('#NewOrder input[name=quantity]').val()) > 0) {
        qnty = Number($('#NewOrder input[name=quantity]').val())
    }

    else {
        alert('Invalid Quantity');
        $('#NewOrder input[name=quantity]').focus(); // ** Working
        return;
    }
    if ($('#NewOrder input[name=rate]').val().length == 0) {
        rate = 0;
    }
    else {
        if (!Number($('#NewOrder input[name=rate]').val() > 0)) {
            alert('Invaid Rate');     // ** Working
            alert($('#NewOrder input[name="rate"]').val()); // ** Working
            $('#NewOrder input[name="rate"]').focus();      // ** Not Working
            $('#NewOrder input[name="rate"]').trigger('focus'); // Also not Works
            return;
        }
        else
            rate = Number($('#NewOrder input[name=rate]').val());
    }
    var mat = getMaterialFromArray($('#mats').find(':selected').text());
    $('#mats').focus();
}
```

Friends where I am going wrong..? What thing am I missing..??
It is irritating me.
While `alert($('#NewOrder input[name="rate"]').val());` says the actual value, means control is being selected using jQuery.
But neither `$('#NewOrder input[name="rate"]').focus();` nor `$('#NewOrder input[name="rate"]').trigger('focus');` works.

**Added Live Version Link**
try accessing http://a.bobdn.com use '111' as Investor No. and 'abc' as password. Then navigate to Material -> New Order and pleeease look what is wrong there.

Comment: It'll help if you show us your HTML code. I've created jsfiddle with what you trying to achieve and it works http://jsfiddle.net/jrbK5/

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov here is the HTML http://a.bobdn.com/RequestedHTML.txt

Comment: What errors did you get in console?

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov I am surprised. Your fiddle is also not working. In fiddle we should not be able to lose focus from `input name="rate"`. I can leave this control simply using `Tab` key or simple by mouse.

Comment: I am getting no error in console. Control is moving just to the next element.

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi In which browser? His fiddle works fine for me in chrome

Comment: hmm @nbrooks. I have also chrome installed. It is working in chrome. It is not working as expected in Firefox 15.0

Comment: @nbrooks Please try this fiddle in Firefox if you have this installed and tell me if it is working there or not.

Comment: No it's not working for me in FF either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a **bug** in Firefox. In Chrome your code is working as it should.
For support in Firefox you can create a function like:

```
function setFocus(controlSelectorString) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(controlSelectorString).focus();
    }, 0);
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrbK5/4/)

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi what answer do you need? It doesn't work for you? Did you tested it?

Comment: It is working. But why simple `.focus()` or `.trigger('focus')` not working in my case when every thing looks fine. try accessing http://a.bobdn.com use '111' as Investor No. and 'abc' as password. Then navigate to Material -> New Order and pleeease look what is wrong there.

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi this is because of bug in firefox

Comment: hmm +1 you are ry8 @AlexanderLarikov. It is working in chrome. But I am still confused in one thing that the line `$('#NewOrder input[name=quantity]').focus();` can set focus to `input name="quantity"` in Firefox but why line `$('#NewOrder input[name="rate"]').focus();` can't..???

Comment: because `onblur` event attached to `$('#NewOrder input[name="rate"]')`, you trying to set focus immediately after `blur` and firefox can't handle this without workaround

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16151/discussion-between-shashwat-tripathi-and-alexander-larikov)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling a focus at the last line of that function and that is getting called every time the function is called and thats overriding your
focus of textbox.

```
$('#mats').focus();
```

Comment: But he calls `return;` in the `if` block, so that last line is never executed.

Comment: You missed a thing. I have placed a `return;` statement inside the `if() { }` statement. So `$('#mats').focus();` wouldn't be executed. And I want to tell you one this if condition is getting satisfied means there is an error in input then focus is getting to the next control which is a button.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked your [code](http://a.bobdn.com/RequestedHTML.txt) and noticed that you have two text boxes with the same name='Rate'. I think that is the issue. Please change the name and try once.

Comment: Jquery selector says to choose input field with `name="rate"` inside element with id `NewOrder`, so its not the issue.

Comment: but inside `#NewOrder`, I have only one control with `name="rate"`.